# PKB2 Search and Narrow functions returning a default VF page instead of custom VF page

Tags: knowledge

So I'm using PKB2 to create a customer facing knowledge base. I've followed the App Guide, and made clones of all of the pages that the guide says to. I've replaced all of the references to the default pages in the clone files as well. And all pages have been provided access in the Public Settings of the profile as well.

The issue is, when I either search using the search field or use the narrowing filters on the left, the URL changes from my custom home URL of:

https://developer-companyName.cs23.force.com/help/?l=en_US

to:

https://developer-companyName.cs23.force.com/help/pkb_Home?l=en_US&c=Publishing%3AUnit

As you can see, the second URL has the /pkb_Home (a reference to the default page) instead of my custom page (which is labeled pkb_Home_clone).

So when a search or narrow is performed, it's removing all of my CSS and other custom functionality because the default home VF page is being called.

Any idea why the default page is being called instead of my custom home page? If I modify the URL manually, and add the '_clone' to the end of the Home portion of the URL, then my custom code shows up. Not sure where to look for the reference to the default, or why it's not choosing my custom VF page.

Any thoughts on this?
Do I need to change the pkb_narrow VF page?

Thanks for any help. Happy to share screenshots if needed, just didn't want to bloat the question.

-Kurt
​Mixpo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the advice. I gave that a shot, and I was still being redirected to the default page. However, upon further digging/banging head on desk, I found the pkb_js file that actually holds the value for the homepage.

At the beginning of some of the variable declarations, it shows the 'home' option. By changing this, the pages are now functioning as expected. I'm betting there's some fun tidbits in that JS file.

Here's where I found it - just a few lines down from the top, the pkb_Home variable is declared:

```
var contactUs = {!pkbCon.displayContactUs};
var viewingArticle = {!pkbCon.viewingArticle};
var pkbHome = "{!IF(pkbCon.facebook,$Page.pkb_Home_fb,$Page.pkb_Home_clone)}";
var openDialogWhenReady = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a PKB component named pkb_article that you can find in your Eclipse. That component defines the link behavior. In particular, there is a nonSiteArticleURL variable which value is set to:

```
<apex:variable var="nonSiteArticleURL" value="{!$Page.pkb_Home}?id={!aid}&"/>
```

You would need to change this to:

```
<apex:variable var="nonSiteArticleURL" value="{!$Page.pkb_Home_clone}?id={!aid}&" />
```

Matt